# MobX + React makes me mad

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-react

First of all, I am not experienced React developer. Just let you know.

I have a store:

```
import {observable, action, reaction, computed, autorun} from 'mobx';
import scrollTo from 'react-scroll-to-component'
```

class ActivePostsStore {

```
  @observable _posts = new Map()
  @observable _visiblePosts = new Set()

  @computed get visiblePosts() {
    return this._visiblePosts
  }

  @action
  addPost(uuid, ref) {
    // console.log('add post')
    this._posts.set(uuid, ref)
  }

  @action
  scrollToPost(uuid) {
    // console.log('scroll to post')
    scrollTo(this._posts.get(uuid), {})
  }

  @action
  addVisiblePost(uuid) {
    console.log('add vis post', this._visiblePosts.values())
    this._visiblePosts.add(uuid)
  }

  @action
  removeVisiblePost(uuid) {
    console.log('rem vis post', this._visiblePosts.values())
    this._visiblePosts = new Set([...this._visiblePosts].filter(el => el !== uuid))
  }

  // reacts = reaction(() => this._visiblePosts, () => console.log('===='))
  // reactToVisiblePosts() {
  //
  // }
}


const store = new ActivePostsStore()
export default store
```

My first problem, that I can pass store through Provider in my Layout Component or _document.js (I use Next.js).

```
/*Doesn't work. In root layout*/
<Provider store={ActivePostsStore}>
  <Content />
</Provider>
```

Every time when I tried to use `Provider` I got my store undefined. In RootLayout or _document.js too. Sure, I provided `@observer` annotation for component which use store. But store is still undefined.

Then, I tried to use `@inject('activePostsStore')` result is Error, that tells me, like I didn't provide any store at all. But, actually, I did.

SO! I decided to inject it directly like:

```
@inject(() => ({
  store: ActivePostsStore
}))
@observer
```

Finally, I can use actions to add or remove elements for `visiblePosts` (i log it). BUT! My store props does not react at all, if I change state of store. For example it does not react to adding new entries to visiblePosts. Or it even can be undefined if I reload page. My code for component is:

```
render() {
    const {classes} = this.props
    return (
      <div className={classNames(classes.postsTree)}>
        {this.props.store.visiblePosts}
        {this.state.groupedDates !== undefined && this.state.groupedDates.map(([date, posts], index) =>
          <PostsTreeGroup
            active={_.some(posts.map(([uuid]) => uuid), uuid => this.props.store.visiblePosts.has(uuid))}
            key={date}
            date={date}
            posts={posts}/>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Can somebody help me to make things works, please!

Comment: Horrible title, not according the SO's guidelines

Answer (score 5):

**Question1:**

Provider only works when you call inject on your component, where you want the store to appear in its props. So you have to call inject, otherwise the store is undefined (because no one set the component's property for your store).

The string you pass to inject must be exactly the property name you gave it in your Provider.

You have:

```
<Provider store={ActivePostsStore}> // store is the property name
```

So you also have to call

```
@inject('store')
```

Then mobx looks for the key store, finds it in your provider and assigns it to your component.

**Question2:**

You would calculate your visible posts in your store and not the other way round. 
So the method visiblePosts only returns visible posts.

Store:

```
@computed get visiblePosts() {
  return this._visiblePosts.map(uuid => this._posts.get(uuid));
}
```

Then in your component you can render only the visible posts:

Component:

```
this.props.store.visiblePosts.map(post => {
 return <PostsTreeGroup ...>
})
```

I also see you do some sort of sorting?

You would then tell your store how to sort (e.g. set a property ) and then let your store do the sorting in the visiblePosts method.

Answer (score 3):

Small addition: it seems at first sight that you are passing a *class* to the provider rather then an *instance* thereof (`ActivePostsStore`). Make sure to instantiate your class so that you get an actual store to work with. (If you did create an instance, then best stick the convention to use lowercase first letter)